System installation stuck
I started installing the system, but it froze at this stage:
Nov 06 12:38:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.4136[7436]: Verifying /dev/sdc1 partition flag, expecting boot, found boot
Nov 06 12:38:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.4136[7436]: Running command ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--bytes', '--pairs', '--output=ALIGNMENT,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO,FSTYPE,GROUP,KNAME,LABEL,LOG-SEC,MAJ:MIN,MIN-IO,MODE,MODEL,MOUNTPOINT,NAME,OPT-IO,OWNER,PHY-SEC,RM,RO,ROTA,RQ-SIZE,SIZE,STATE,TYPE,UUID', '/dev/sdc1'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Nov 06 12:38:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.4136[7436]: Resize requested for format ntfs
Nov 06 12:38:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.4136[7436]: Verifying /dev/sdc2 size, expecting 8589934592 bytes, found 8589934592 bytes
Nov 06 12:38:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.4136[7436]: Verifying /dev/sdc2 offset, expecting 1991806812160, found 1991806812160
Nov 06 12:38:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.4136[7436]: Resizing /dev/sdc1 of type ntfs down to 1403538898944
Nov 06 12:38:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.4136[7436]: Running command ['ntfsresize', '-f', '-s', '1403538898944', '/dev/sdc1'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)

What can I do with it?

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details, somewhat limiting what we can actually offer in advice. Did you check your ISO prior to writing to your media for faults? (as per documentation) or verify write of ISO to media?  (or did you scan & confirm that completed on your install machine?)

Depending on the size and type of the drive and how much data is on it - I suspect a resize could take quite a while. Always take a backup before doing stuff like this.
